# ggplot2 - geom_ribbon bug?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code throws an error and I can't figure out why...

```
library( plyr )
library( ggplot2 )
library( grid )
library( proto )

# the master dataframe
myDF = structure(list(Agg52WkPrceRange = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), OfResidualPntReturn52CWk = c(0.201477324, 
0.22350293, 0.248388728, 0.173871456, 0.201090654, 0.170666183, 
0.18681883, 0.178840521, 0.159744891, 0.129811042, 0.13209741, 
0.114989407, 0.128347625, 0.100945992, 0.057017002, 0.081123718, 
0.018900252, 0.021784814, 0.081931816, 0.059067844, 0.095879746, 
0.038977508, 0.078895248, 0.051344317, 0.077515295, 0.011776214, 
0.099216033, 0.054714439, 0.022879951, -0.079558277, -0.050889584, 
-0.006934821, -0.003407085, 0.032545474, -0.003387139, 0.030418511, 
0.053942523, 0.051398537, 0.073482355, 0.087963039, 0.079555591, 
-0.040490418, -0.130754663, -0.125826649, -0.141766316, -0.150708718, 
-0.171906882, -0.174623614, -0.212945405, -0.174480554), IndependentVariableBinned = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Agg52WkPrceRange", 
"OfResidualPntReturn52CWk", "IndependentVariableBinned"), row.names = 28653:28702, class = "data.frame")

# secondary data frame
meansByIndependentVariableBin = ddply( myDF , .( IndependentVariableBinned ) , function( df ) mean( df[[ "OfResidualPntReturn52CWk" ]] ) )

# construct the plot
thePlot = ggplot( myDF , aes_string( x = "IndependentVariableBinned" , y = "OfResidualPntReturn52CWk" ) )
thePlot = thePlot + geom_point( data = meansByIndependentVariableBin , aes( x = IndependentVariableBinned , y = V1 ) )
thePlot = thePlot + geom_line( data = meansByIndependentVariableBin , aes( x = IndependentVariableBinned , y = V1 , group = 1 )  )
thePlot = thePlot + geom_ribbon( data = meansByIndependentVariableBin , aes( group = 1 ,  x = IndependentVariableBinned , ymin = V1 - 1 , ymax = V1 + 1 ) )

# print - error!
print( thePlot )
```

I've tried with/without group=1.  The error is:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  object 'OfRelStrength52CWk' not found
```

but not sure how that is relevant??  I must be missing something obvious. Take away the last geom (ribbon) and it plots just fine!

Comment: Can you provide the `dput()` of myDF? Or a subset of it to illustrate your problem so others can attempt to duplicate.

Comment: Its a fairly large data table...even if I subset to just x/y.  I know that y is never NA.  x can have NA.  IndependentVariableBinned bins the x's from 1 to 10 and places NAs in its own NA bin.  does this help or should I try to output data?

Comment: I think I'd try and output the (relevant) data. If you do something like `head(dput(myDF), 50)` it should be pretty managable and hopefully will reproduce the error you are seeing.

Comment: @Chase - GREAT suggestion.  I've reworked the original post.  This reduced example produces the same failure.  Could you take a look?

Comment: @SFun can you please not name such long data frame names and variable names. I got killed trying to type those terms correctly without typos. Last resort I renamed them to shorter names!

Comment: @SFun, @Ramnath - typing this stuff out made me think of this commercial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUdV6lC7ZNI

Comment: @Chase - HA!  nice vid.  sorry...as a best-practice I use long/descriptive variable names.  I notice the R community likes to use vars like x, nx, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no bug in `geom_ribbon`. Your error is because you are defining `y = OfResidualPntReturn52CWk` in your ggplot call as a result of which `geom_ribbon` is looking for it. Since you are passing a different data frame to `geom_ribbon`, there is confusion and hence an error. From your plotting call, although you are using `y = OfResidualPntReturn52CWk` in your ggplot call, there is no layer where you are calling it, and hence it is immaterial to the plot.

Here is how to do it correctly (if I am understanding what you intend to do in this plot)

```
MIVB    = meansByIndependentVariableBin
thePlot = ggplot(myDF , aes(x = IndependentVariableBinned)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = OfResidualPntReturn52CWk)) +
  geom_point(data = MIVB, aes(y = V1), colour = 'red') + 
  geom_line(data = MIVB , aes(y = V1, group = 1), colour = 'red') +
  geom_ribbon(data = MIVB, aes(group = 1, ymin = V1 - 1 , ymax = V1 + 1), 
     alpha = 0.2)
```

Here is the output it produces
[image]

Here is another way to do it, without computing the means in advance. Also I have used mean +- standard errors in the ribbon as I find the choice of +- 1 to be arbitrary

```
myDF$IndependentVariableBinned = as.numeric(myDF$IndependentVariableBinned)
thePlot = ggplot(myDF , aes(x = IndependentVariableBinned, y = 
   OfResidualPntReturn52CWk)) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_point(stat = 'summary', fun.y = 'mean', colour = 'red') + 
   geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = 'mean', colour = 'red') +
   geom_ribbon(stat = 'summary', fun.data = 'mean_se', alpha = 0.2)
```

This produces
[image]

Comment: @Ramnath - I thought ggplot has the ability to layer different data frames?  Although in this particular example the y = OfResidualPntReturn52CWk is immaterial, this is just a reduced example and I may in fact use that y.  Maybe there's some core concept I'm missing here?  I explicitly define ymin and ymax in the geom_ribbon call...isn't that sufficient?

Comment: @Ramnath - another way to state this is how can I keep the ggplot(...) line and fix up the code to show the ribbon?

Comment: @SFun. Yes you are. But by defining `y` in your global ggplot call, all layers will try to find that variable no matter what data frame you use. Hence it is always advisable to define your variables only in the layer you intend to use them in. See my example in the answer

Comment: @Ramnath - could you take a look at my comment to @Chase's answer?  I'd still like to know how to preserve my original y assignment (only to learn about how ggplot works)

Comment: @SFun. the other option you have is to explicitly define `y = NULL` in the `geom_ribbon` layer so that it overrides the default. This will not throw an error since `geom_ribbon` does not need `y` anyways. Try this modification in your code and it should work

Comment: @Ramnath - AH!  that makes sense.  If I call plot = ggplot() with no parameters then does that mean there will be no global variables?  each layer on top of plot will be somehow "local"?

Comment: @Ramnath - thanks for all of your help.  You and @Chase should write a book about this stuff =)

Comment: @SFun. glad to be of help. learning ggplot has been a journey and i have begun to appreciate its elegance at every step

Answer (score 3):

@Ramnath is spot on. Your initial call to `ggplot` is not needed as all of the layers you are plotting come from the summarized `data.frame` made by `ddply()`. You can also simplify your call to `ddply()` by using the `summarize` function:

```
meansByIndependentVariableBin2 = ddply( myDF , .( IndependentVariableBinned ) 
, summarize, means = mean(OfResidualPntReturn52CWk) )
```

I would then plot your graph as such:

```
ggplot(meansByIndependentVariableBin2, aes(x = as.numeric(IndependentVariableBinned), y = means)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = (means - 1), ymax = (means + 1)), alpha = .4) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line()
```

Is that what you had in mind? I added an alpha to the ribbon layer so we can see the lines and points clearly.

[image]

Comment: @Chase - really appreciate the ddply simplification (teaches me about ddply!) as well as the alpha suggestion which would probably have been my next question =).  I'm still confused though...I totally get that I'm not using my orignal y, but what if I was?  I'm trying to understand how ggplot works.  If I were using my original y then is this scenario impossible?

Comment: I'll see if I can dig up the reference in the ggplot book, but essentially - any aesthetics defined in `ggplot(aes())` will be passed to every subsequent layer, so if you have an aesthetic that is only used by a particular layer, don't put it in the initial call to `ggplot()`. That is why I moved the `ymin()` and `ymax()` to the `geom_ribbon` layer. I'm not entirely sure which layer you would want to use the "original y" in, but you could add it at the layer level as you did in your first post. For some complicated plots that combine data from 3+ datasets, I have started

Comment: with a blank call to `ggplot()` and then defined my data and geom for every layer. Something like `ggplot() + geom_polygon(data1, aes(x,y)) + geom_line(data2, aes(x,y)) + geom_xx(dataxx, ...)`

Comment: @Chase - that makes sense!  So essentially the original ggplot() call makes aesthetics global whereas all layers have aesthetics that are local to the layer?  Or is it that layers have aesthetics local to themselves and previous layers?

Comment: The data and aesthetics are local to that particular layer. Compare `ggplot() + geom_point(data = dat, aes(x,y)) + geom_line(data = dat, aes(x,y))` vs `ggplot() + geom_point(data = dat, aes(x,y)) + geom_line()` with `dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))` defined as the data.

Comment: @Chase - thanks for all of your help.  I really appreciate it. I'll award points to @Ramnath since he provided the first solution, but honestly wish I could mark both as answer.

Comment: No worries, glad to help. @Ramnath's answer (especially the last edit) is probably the most efficient solution here thinking big picture. More than one way to slice a cat :)

Comment: I guess you could skin the cat too...slice/dice/skin...really all one and the same. Ok, bedtime.